# Type 'ScopeType<T, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ParentScopeType<S>' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In my large compiler project, I have isolated the error code to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgZygJwCqVgXhgb2DGKAWwEMBLAGwC4YERkyA7Ac2AF9hQMYBlAYwD20dNAA8PADQwACoQAeIKIwAmCGAFdGAa0YCA7oxjZNO-YwB8R3PhjKSIEjR42IJZEpAB+GrKgKlqryCwhiiTABmKDCoUhFRAIrmNgSeQUJQIlCiMTCJyTA0jFAAbijsnODQMgIICGQARhRQ-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):

```
type UserType = {
  email: string
}

type ScopeType<S, P extends unknown = unknown> = {
  data: S
  parent?: P extends ScopeType<infer T, infer Q>
    ? ScopeType<T, Q>
    : never
}

type PossibleScopeType<ST> = ST extends ScopeType<
  infer S,
  infer P
>
  ? ST | (P extends ScopeType<infer A, infer B> ? (P | PossibleScopeType<P>) : never)
  : never

type ModuleType = {
  path: string
}

const scope: ScopeType<ModuleType> = {
  data: {
    path: './foo.x',
  },
}

const scope2: ScopeType<UserType, ScopeType<ModuleType>> = {
  data: {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
  },
  parent: scope,
}

let scope3: PossibleScopeType<typeof scope2> = scope
scope3 = scope

let scope4: PossibleScopeType<ScopeType<UserType, ScopeType<ModuleType>>> = scope
scope3 = scope

export type ParentScopeType<S> =
  // | S
  S extends ScopeType<infer X, infer Y> ? S : S

function test<T, S extends ScopeType<T>>(scope: S): void {
  let source: ParentScopeType<S> | undefined = scope
  console.log(source)
}

test<UserType, ScopeType<UserType>>(scope2)
```

In the function `test` at the bottom, this line throws an error at `source`:

```
let source: ParentScopeType<S> | undefined = scope
```

It says:

```
Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'ParentScopeType<S> | undefined'.
  Type 'ScopeType<T, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ParentScopeType<S>'.(2322)
```

I have struggled with this for a few hours. Literally in this case I am just debugging, and in `ParentScopeType` I simply return `S` (`ScopeType`) in both conditional branches! If I comment out the conditional branching and just put the following, it compiles:

```
type ParentScopeType<S> = S
```

That is the same as doing:

```
function test<T, S extends ScopeType<T>>(scope: S): void {
  let source: S | undefined = scope
  console.log(source)
}
```

I don't see why the conditional branch changes the logic at all, because it is returning `S` in both branches... Something is fishy with this, my understanding of how conditional types work must be off. Can you show me how I can keep the function `test` as is, and get it to compile? The `ParentScopeType` should be a type of the current scope and all its parents, like `Scope1 | Scope1Parent | Scope1ParentParent | ...`.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgZygJwCqVgXhgb2DGKAWwEMBLAGwC4YERkyA7Ac2AF9hQMYBlAYwD20dNAA8PADQwACoQAeIKIwAmCGAFdGAa0YCA7oxjZNO-YwB8R3PhjKSIEjR42IJZEpAB+GrKgKlqryCwhiiTABmKDCoUhFRAIrmNgSeQUJQIlCiMTCJyTA0jFAAbijsnODQMgIICGQARhRQ-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-cDIKgX4BSfEBRBlQtoGLHMsnozIvwTMVXiAA) is another slight variation, same error.

An even more primitive example is:

```
type ParentType<S> = S extends object ? string : number

function test2<T>(scope: T): void {
  let source: ParentType<T> | undefined = 'hello'
  console.log(source)
}
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ParentType<T>'
```

Why is it not working like I'd expect? Shouldn't `source: string | number` in the last example?

It compiles like this though:

```
type ParentType<S> = S extends string ? string : unknown

function test2<T>(scope: T): void {
  let source: ParentType<T> | undefined = 'hello'
  console.log(source)
}
```

I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, it has to do with the fact that conditional types become distributive when handed a union type (see the handbook [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)).

This fails:

```
type Generic<T> = T extends string ? T : T;

function test<T>(t: T): void {
  const x: Generic<T> = t; // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Generic<T>'.
}
```

To counter the distributive behavior, you can wrap the type parameter being checked in a tuple, so this works:

```
type Generic<T> = [T] extends [string] ? T : T;

function test<T>(t: T): void {
  const x: Generic<T> = t; // OK
}
```

For your example, if you change your `ParentScopeType` as below, you'll get rid of the compiler error:

```
export type ParentScopeType<S> = [S] extends [ScopeType<unknown>] ? S : S;
```